# My query is returning one record, but without any data in it

Tags: soql, related-list, relationships

I have this query to get the related data and update it, if it exists. In interface im not seeing any data, but sfdc somehow is fetching one row without any values in it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You query means:

Fetch a record with Id = `yourID` and in that record show me all related `Key_StakeHolders__r` data too.

As you dont have any other other fields in SOQL, thus it is able to fetch the record with the given `Id`, but there is no related  `Key_StakeHolders__r` in that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar query on account and contact. The result is same.When you see results 1, it means, query has returned something. In your case it is returning the `Use_Case__c` record with Id field. To better understand the result, try running the same query in anonymous window and debug the return result. It will look something like `DEBUG|(Use_Case__c:{Id=a8H2T0000005loVUA5})`. In the query editor, it only shows data for the fields you have mentioned in the query. Because there were no fields mentioned for `Use_Case__c`, it is not showing anything from the query result. Instead, it is showing `Key_Stakeholders__r` is empty, as you have mentioned field in the inner query.

Hope this helps you. Good luck.